# StringUtils splits based on regex

Tags: java, regex, apache-stringutils

I have a following code to split my input String:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class SplitTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "A||B||||D||E";
        String result[] = StringUtils.split(input, "||");

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("result[" + i + "]:" + result[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And I was expecting output as:

**Expected Output:**

```
 result[0]:A
 result[1]:B
 result[2]:
 result[3]:D
 result[4]:E
```

**Real Output:**

```
result[0]:A
result[1]:B
result[2]:D
result[3]:E
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? What Can I do to achieve my expected output?

Comment: `input.split()` from the [standard Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) will give you want you need, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [`StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String result[] = StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens(input, "||");
```

You could also achieve the same result with standard Java and without library with `String.split()` and a regular expression:

```
String result[] = input.split("\\|\\|");
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that String#split will have to compile the regex every time it's called. I don't understand why they didn't overload that function with a `Pattern` argument.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says, that adjacent separators are treated as one separator

[http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Try using StrTokenizer instead

```
String input = "A||B||||D||E";
StrTokenizer tokenizer = new StrTokenizer(input, "||");
tokenizer.setIgnoreEmptyTokens(false);

for (int i = 0; i < tokenizer .getTokenArray().length; i++) {
    System.out.println("result[" + i + "]:" + tokenizer.getTokenArray()[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior of `StringUtils.split`. This method will not return empty results.

See more: [StringUtils::split(String, String) documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

My solution will be:

```
public class SplitTest {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "A||B||||D||E";
    String result[] = input.split("[|]{2}");

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("result[" + i + "]:" + result[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Or:

[StringUtils::splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens(String, String) documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)